# How to access child component inside ngb-tab (For validation purposes)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Suppose having this template(for parent component)

```
<button ... (click)="Save()">
...
<ngb-tabset [activeId]="selectedTab" #tabs>
  <ngb-tab id="tab1">
    <template ngbTabTitle>tab1</template>
    <template ngbTabContent>
      <child-comp1 #comp1>
      </child-comp1>
    </template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="tab2">
    <template ngbTabTitle>tab2</template>
    <template ngbTabContent>
      <child-comp2 #comp2>
      </child-comp2>
    </template>
  </ngb-tab>
  ...
</ngb-tabset>
```

And inside each child component(child-comp1 ...) I have a form and inputs with some validations.

How can I access child's component method from the parent component **on demand**,
I mean something like this:

```
Save(){
  if(Validate()){
    //Save an object ...
  }
}

Validate(){
  if(!this.comp1.Validate()){
    // Activate tab1
    return false;
  }
  else if(!this.comp2.Validate()){
    // Activate tab2
    return false;
  }
  //...
  return true;      
}
```

In parent component I have:

```
// imports ...
@Component({ ... })
export class parent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComp) comp1: ChildComp;
  @ViewChild('comp2') comp2;
  @ViewChild('tabs') tabs;
  ...
  Validate(){...}
  Save(){...}
}
```

`comp1` and `comp2` are always `undefined` in the validation method!

`tabs` return an object, but I couldn't find a way to reach the child component !

Comment: Did you check in the constructor or `ngAfterViewInit()`? `@ViewChild()` isn't assigned yet in the constructor. Also some more code would be helpful. Where is the `@ViewChild(....)` and related code. Where is the HTML shown in your question?

Comment: In the `Validate()` method which is after clicking a button.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I updated the question a little. I hope it's more clear now!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, a simple fix would be to set [destroyOnHide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api) input property to false, which prevents tabs from being destroyed when they get hidden.

```
<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false">
  ...
</ngb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case issue was connected with two things:

1. Had to use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOninit`
2. `ngb-tabset` was wrapped with `*ngIf` statement. Changed to `[hidden]`

P.S for those who encountered this issue when trying to create dynamic component here is the code also for that part:

**HTML**

```
  <ngb-tabset type="pills" [orientation]="currentOrientation">
    <div #dynamicComponent></div>
  </ngb-tabset>
```

**TS**

```
 @ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

 constructor(   
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const component = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TabComponent)
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(component)
    ref.instance.someValue = 'something'
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are inside the `<template>` tag. These elements are not created like they are shown in the template. 
How they are actually created in the DOM depends on what `<ngb-tab>` does with the template it gets passed to.

I think it's necessary to use `ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` or similar instead.